# Tcp Server on Another thread- could data be unread when another thread takes the cpu/core?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have my main Winforms application.
There are 6 Threads working in parrael + main thread, atleast that is what it ment to be .
I have created one Thread that is an Tcp Server, listening on specific port.

```
listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening));
listenerThread.Start();
```

I have also 5 different Threads that are doing different kind of stuff (for example updating database, counting averages/sums, being TCP Clients etc.)

My question is:
Is it possible that my TCP Server (which is working on one of 6 threads) wont read a message when one of those 5 different threads thread will take the computing power of CPU, and the TCP Server's Thread thread will have to wait ?

Another question: If that could happend, how could i avoid that ?

Comment: Why are you spinning up threads to handle a single connection?  For that matter why are you spinning up a thread for an _**asynchronous** socket server?_ Spinning up threads for I/O-bound code (including databases) is inefficient and spinning up a thread per connection does not scale.  Look into I/O completion ports or simply use code that supports `async/await`.

Comment: _"Is it possible that my TCP Server (which is working on one of 6 threads) wont read a message when one of those 5 different threads thread will take the computing power of CPU, and the TCP Server's Thread thread will have to wait ?"_ - received data is buffered to an extent however if your code does not respond in an appropriate time then it could result in dropped data.  The same could be said in a single-core system and another app running next to yours _isn't playing nice_.

Comment: @MickyD: i want to put work that needs to be done (inserts,updates) in another thread, to dont slow the main thread. Sometimes database will reply me in 30ms, and sometimes 300ms, i cannot let that happen that database would slow down entire process, thats why i want to delegate this task for another thread. This application in main thread has to be very fast, thats why i put (what i can) in another thread's. That TCP server indeed  could be tho in the Main Thread, i just wanted the main thread to be as fast as possible.

Comment: _"in another thread, to dont slow the main thread."_ - again, look into `async/await` for the situation you described is quite common and can be solved without child threads.  NHibernate, Entity Framework and even plain ol' ADO.NET (albeit via legacy `IAsyncResult `) support asynchronous I/O where no explicit child thread is required to be spun up.  Threads are a finite resource and creating one is expensive in terms of computer resources.

Comment: @MickyD: im not using any ORM, because for example: Entity framework is too slow, and too big, for such a simple operations that i do on database. Im using an dapper.

Comment: _"im not using any ORM"_ - did you miss it when I said _"and even plain ol' **ADO.NET** (albeit via legacy IAsyncResult ) support asynchronous I/O where no explicit child thread is required to be spun up"_

Comment: @MickyD: i could check that, It might be worth giving a try.

Comment: Your recent edit have invalidated the above comments and potentially any existing answers.  I have rolled it back.  _["Editing a question so that the provided answers are invalid is not the right way for the original user to get assistance. If they have further questions, they should post a new question, not invalidate the help they've already been given."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351629/585968)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is a summary of my comments above

---

> "Is it possible that my TCP Server (which is working on one of 6 threads) wont read a message when one of those 5 different threads thread will take the computing power of CPU, and the TCP Server's Thread thread will have to wait ?"

Received data is buffered to an extent however if your code does not respond in an appropriate time then it could result in dropped data.

The same could be said in a single-core system and another app, say *Prime95* is busy not playing nice and calculating prime numbers right next to yours.

> Another question: If that could happend, how could i avoid that ?

When handling I/O and I'll focus on TCP here is to perform the minimal amount of processing in your data received handler irrespective of whether that handler is of the form `IAsyncResult` or `async/await`.

A good general flow is:

1. start an asynchronous read
2. read result of asynchronous read
3. place result in a queue
4. loop back to #1

Meanwhile you process the read results from #2 in a different mechanism whether that be a timer; GUI app-idle-loop; or a different thread so long as the thread processing the results has nothing to do with the flow above.

The reason being is that in a scenario involving *reasonably high data transfer rates*, if you were to read a block of data and then proceed to immediately update that *Telerik* datagrid UI showing 1000s of rows, there is a high chance that the next read operation will result in dropped data because you didn't respond in a sufficient amount of time.

Comment: Actually that answer is almost solving my question, almost. I think i should update my question a little bit and give a more detailed description.